# Make a plugin for adobe illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, plugins

I'm not sure if I am posting this question in the right place but I was wondering if anybody knew how I would make a plugin for illustrator?

Thanks...

Comment: Hi, I just published a short updated tutorial about how to create an extension for Adobe Illustrator / Photoshop with CEP7 if you're interested 

https://medium.com/@jolg42/how-to-create-an-html5-javascript-extension-for-adobe-illustrator-photoshop-cc-78921802e248#.vcoqlxsnn

Comment: This question was posted a long time ago, but you don't give any first attempt or precisions about your goals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't specify which version of Illustrator you are targeting, but you can find the [SDKs for CS5 on Adobe's site](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/sdk.html). A bit of digging will probably reveal previous versions. The SDK will give all of the information you need to code and compile.